# What is the difference between a popup and a popover (i.e. NSPopupButton vs UIPopoverController)?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

Why was the name popover chosen as opposed to a hypothetical UIPopupController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's popping over the UI at a non-deterministic location depending on available space. It's not popping up at a certain location.